# Getting "OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long" in an attempt to collect data in txt files

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk, python-re, nameerror

There is something wrong with my code and I have no idea what. I'm a beginner so I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is obvious. When I run this, I get:
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long. If I had to guess, I think I failed to tokenize my files but I don't know how to solve that. Whenever I replaced the name of the text with the "token" version", I get a name error.

````
moonstone = open("../150C/The_Moonstone.txt", encoding = "UTF_8").read()
TGP = open("../150C/The_Garden_Party_&_Other_Stories.txt", encoding = "UTF_8").read()
austen = open("../150C/Austen.txt", encoding = "latin_1").read()

def cleanandtokenize(moonstone):
    textlower = moonstone.lower
    textcleaner = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', textlower)
    moonstone = nltk.word_tokenize(textcleaner)
    return token_moonstone
                 
def cleanandtokenize(TGP):
        textlower = TGP.lower
        textcleaner = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', textlower)
        token_TGP = nltk.word_tokenize(textcleaner)
        return token_TGP
                 
def cleanandtokenize(austen):
    textlower = austen.lower
    textcleaner = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', textlower)
    token_austen = nltk.word_tokenize(textcleaner)
    return token_austen

textdict = {
    "texts":[
        {
            "moonstone": moonstone, 
            "The Garden Party": TGP,
            "Austen": austen
        }
    ]
}

def longest_words(textdict):
    with open(textdict) as file:
        words = file.read().split('')
    max_len = len(max(words, key=len))
    return [word for word in words if len(word) == max_len]


print(f"*The Moonstone*: {longest_words(moonstone)}",
      f"*The Garden Party and Other Stories*: {longest_words(TGP)}",
      f"*Jane Austens Works*: {longest_words(austen)}",
      sep="\n\n")```
````

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Also, please [edit] to indicate the precise filename you are having trouble with. The ones in your question all look fine, even for Windows (but probably also include your OS in the question, since the rules for what's allowed differ between platforms).